# Java arraylist retrieving data min/max values

Tags: java

I am doing my Java homework for a class.  I wrote the below store program that the user inputs a 4 digit id and what money they had for that store id.  This information get's put in an array.  totals and store id's are retrieved.
in the next part of my program I am to retrieve min and max values from each data group:even and odd store id numbers.  I have tried to do this by retrieving the origonal data and putting them into a new array.  even data into an even array and odd data into an odd array.  in the following code I am testing the even part.  Once it works I will replicate in the odd section.
Right now the following code skips my request.  I don't know how to fix this.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Bonus
{

    public static void main (String[] arg)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String storeID, highID;
        double grandTotalSales = 0;
        double evenGrandTotal = 0;
        double oddGrandTotal = 0;
        double evenTotalSale;
        double oddTotalSale;
        double largestYet = 0;
        double maxValue = 0;
        int numPenn, numNick, numDime, numQuar, numHalf, numDol;
        boolean more = true;
        boolean report = true;
        String input;
        int inputopt;
        char cont;
        char check1, highStoreID;
        Store myStore;
        ArrayList<Store> storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
        ArrayList<Store> evenStoreList = new ArrayList<Store>();

        while(more)
        {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 4 digit store ID");
        storeID = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter num of Penny");
        numPenn = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter num of Nickel");
        numNick = in.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Enter num of Dime");
        numDime = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter num of Quarter");
        numQuar = in.nextInt();


        System.out.println("Enter num of Half dollars");
        numHalf = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter num of Dollar bills");
        numDol = in.nextInt();

        myStore = new Store(storeID, numPenn, numNick, numDime, numQuar, numHalf, numDol);
        storeList.add(myStore);

        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("More stores: Yes or No");
        input = in.nextLine();
        cont = input.charAt(0);

        if((cont == 'N')||(cont == 'n'))
            more = false;

        }
        while(report)
        {
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("What would you like to do?  \nEnter: \n1 print Odd Store ID's report \n2 print Even Store ID's report \n3 to Exit");
                inputopt = in.nextInt();
                if(inputopt == 2)
                {

                System.out.println("\nEven Store ID's Report:");
                System.out.println("Store ID" + " | " + " Total Sales" + " | " + "Even Total Sales");

                for(int i = 0; i < storeList.size(); ++i)
                {
                    myStore = (Store)(storeList.get(i));
                    storeID = myStore.getStoreID();

                    check1 = storeID.charAt(3);
                    if(check1 == '0' || check1 == '2' || check1 == '4'|| check1 == '6' || check1 =='8')
                    {
                        myStore.findEvenValue();

                        evenTotalSale = myStore.getEvenValue();
                        evenGrandTotal = evenGrandTotal + Store.getEvenValue();

                        System.out.println((storeList.get(i)).getStoreID() + "     | " + (storeList.get(i)).getEvenValue() + "   | " + (storeList.get(i)).getEvenGrandValue());

                     }

                    }

                         in = new Scanner(System.in);
                         System.out.println("Do want to print the highest and lowest sales?  \nEnter yes or no");
                         input = in.nextLine();
                         cont = input.charAt(0);
                         if((cont == 'Y')||(cont == 'y'))
                         {
                             evenTotalSale = 0;
                             for(int i = 1; i < evenStoreList.size(); ++i)
                             {
                                myStore = (Store)(evenStoreList.get(i));
                                highID = myStore.getStoreID();
                                    myStore.findEvenValue();
                                    largestYet = myStore.getEvenValue();
                                    if(largestYet > evenTotalSale)
                                    {
                                    Collections.copy(storeList, evenStoreList);
                                    System.out.println("Store ID with highest sales is: ");
                                    System.out.println((evenStoreList.get(i)).getStoreID() + "     | " + largestYet);
                                    }
                               }
                            }
                        else if((cont == 'N')||(cont == 'n'))
                        report = true;

            }
                else
                if(inputopt == 1)
                {
                                System.out.println("\nOdd Store ID's Report:");
                                System.out.println("Store ID" + " | " + " Total Sales" + " | " + " Odd Total Sales");

                    for(int i = 0; i < storeList.size(); ++i)
                    {
                                myStore = (Store)(storeList.get(i));
                                storeID = myStore.getStoreID();

                                check1 = storeID.charAt(3);
                                if(check1 == '1' || check1 == '3' || check1 == '5'|| check1 == '7' || check1 =='9')
                                {
                                myStore.findOddValue();

                                oddTotalSale = myStore.getOddValue();
                                oddGrandTotal = oddGrandTotal + Store.getOddValue();

                                System.out.println((storeList.get(i)).getStoreID() + "     | " + (storeList.get(i)).getOddValue() + "   | " + (storeList.get(i)).getOddGrandValue());
                                }
                   }
                }
                 else
                if(inputopt == 3)
                    report = false;

        } // close while report




    }// close of main



} // close class
```

class store:

```
public class Store
{
private String storeID;
private int numPenn, numNick, numDime, numQuar, numHalf, numDol;
Coin penn = new Coin("Penn", 0.01);
Coin nick = new Coin("Nickel", 0.05);
Coin dime = new Coin("Dime", 0.10);
Coin quar = new Coin("Quar", 0.25);
Coin half = new Coin("Half", 0.50);
Coin dol = new Coin("Dollar", 1.00);
private static double evenTotalSale;
private static double oddTotalSale;
static double evenGrandTotal = 0;
static double oddGrandTotal = 0;



    public Store (String storeID, int numPenn, int numNick, int numDime, int numQuar, int numHalf, int numDol)
    {
        this.storeID = storeID;
        this.numPenn = numPenn;
        this.numNick = numNick;
        this.numDime = numDime;
        this.numQuar = numQuar;
        this.numHalf = numHalf;
        this.numDol = numDol;
     }


public void findEvenValue()
{   evenTotalSale = numPenn * penn.getValue() + numNick * nick.getValue() + numDime * dime.getValue()
                + numQuar * quar.getValue() + numHalf * half.getValue() + numDol * dol.getValue();
     evenGrandTotal = evenGrandTotal + evenTotalSale;
}

public static double getEvenValue()
{
    return evenTotalSale;
}

public void findOddValue()
{   oddTotalSale = numPenn * penn.getValue() + numNick * nick.getValue() + numDime * dime.getValue()
                + numQuar * quar.getValue() + numHalf * half.getValue() + numDol * dol.getValue();
     oddGrandTotal = oddGrandTotal + oddTotalSale;
}

public static double getOddValue()
{
    return oddTotalSale;
}

public static double getOddGrandValue()
{
    return oddGrandTotal;
}

public static double getEvenGrandValue()
{
    return evenGrandTotal;
}
public String getStoreID()
{
    return storeID;
}


}
```

Comment: @pst: it's a "plz i want teh code"

Answer (score 2):

your `evenStoreList` is empty.

Comment: I haven't even the faintest idea if this is correct, but +1 for posting an answer.

Comment: thank you very much!  i appreicate you response!  i know what code i need to add....  :-)